# How to inject properly my vendor from node_modules with gulp

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, gulp, browserify

I'm really getting crazy! 
I have `bower` on my project but since is now deprecated I need to migrate my vendor dependecies.
I'm using `gulp` to automatize injection on index.html.
Now, I want use only npm as package manager. 
I tried mixing [`npmfiles`](https://github.com/cosminlupu/npmfiles) and `browserify`, but my trouble is with the injection of css files and also with the order of the js' injection.

For the first case, `css files` are not catched from node_modules, this behavior is correct because `npmfiles` catch only the main file tagged on packages.json. I?m not been able to find something similar good about gulp + node_modules for css.

Someone of you have experience on that? 
Is using npm for frontend vendor/plugin a logic error?